# How can I make a cell move depending on another cell?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-filter-view

I have a system where there are 2 columns of cells, and in these columns have names and data for the names.

I don't feel comfortable sharing my spreadsheet so here is a example.

```
Food \ Quantity
------ --------
Pasta  | 4

Lemons | 4

Chicken | 4
```

---

But now, code is sent to the quantity and the numbers change.

```
Pasta is now: 2
Lemons is still: 4
Chicken is now: 1
```

Now in the food column (Column E), I want it to move whenever I sort the Quantity column, but I don't want it to lose the correct number.

So Lemons would move as soon as 4 gets sorted to the top of the list. And Pasta would do the same but be 1 cell below. And chicken would be the last again, as if the food cells are basically following their quantity cells.

So now it would automatically update to this.

```
Food \ Quantity
------ --------
Lemons  | 4

Pasta | 2

Chicken | 1
```

---

And I want this to all happen without me manually touching it.

So what formula is needed for this? Im kind of new, so write to me like I'm a 4 year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select range like this:

[image: 0]

then do:

[image: 0]

then click on those 3 lines and sort it as you wish:

[image]

---

script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");     //SHEET NAME
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");          //RANGE TO BE SORTED

function onEdit(e)  {                        //NUMBER OF COLUMN(S) TO BE SORTED
  range.sort([{column: 4, ascending: false}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
}
```

Comment: @TheBoldRoller answer updated with scripted solution